# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, xml, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm really new on Hybris and I'm working on 6.2 version. I decided, after doing some trail, to create a new empty extension to work on.
So, the first step was the creation of a new folder in which import all the "prepared" B2C extension of the platform. After doing this I imported 
the MySQL-connector-java 5.1.9 and I modified my local.properties to connect Hybris to MySQL.

The version of the workbench of my MySQL is the 8.0 and I use them 
MySQL server version 5.5.62 (at the beginning I used the 8.0.13 but then I changed it because I had some problems to connect Hybris).

After running ant clean all, the BUILD was SUCCESFUL. So I run hybrisserver.bat., that was also successful.
At this point I run "ant nextgen" and I passed to the creation of my empty extension. The creation was successful and iI added it also to the localextensions.xml. Added the extension I run first "ant" (following the log instructions), then ant all initialize and at the end I imported all of my extensions in Spring where I simply added two item type and one relation to the `*-items.xml`.

After running ant all the build was successful but when I run hybrisserver.bat, I was not able to log on Hybris because it asked me to initialize it. The initialization failed and that below was the problem.

I've just tried to put "build.development.mode=false" in the local.properties, 
to control Hybris authorizations, to control the XML syntax of the relationship and of its items (even if they are supplied by hybrid and should not be touched, and I didn't touch them) and it looks ok...But I recognize that I'm not able to solve the problem. Can someone help me?

> nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table
>   'test_hybris.promrestr2orderrel' doesn't exist
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:415)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:596)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.DefaultDbScriptsExecutor.executeBatch(DefaultDbScriptsExecutor.java:143)
>   ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
>           ... 138 more Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'test_hybris.promrestr2orderrel' doesn't exist
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:1067)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:482)
>   ~[coreserver.jar:?]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1BatchUpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:557)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1BatchUpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:544)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:596)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>           at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.DefaultDbScriptsExecutor.executeBatch(DefaultDbScriptsExecutor.java:143)
>   ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
>           ... 138 more

Answer (score 0):

What exact version of 6.2 are you using? Try to use the latest 6.2.x.y. Better yet, try to use a more updated version. 6.2 is already EOL (end-of-life).

Also, how about trying to delete the DB schema, and doing another ant clean all initialize?

Comment: Thank you very much, but i solved the problem changing the version of MySql server

Comment: @AndMC What version did you change it to? You should add a new Answer to your question, and mark it as Answered later. :)